# Call to a member function has() on null symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, service

I have 5 class Categoria, Produto, Subcategoria, Subproduto and Comanda and for execute search in all classes i try make a service like:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;


use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class AccessClassController extends Controller{

    /**
     * Retorna todas as categorias ativas
     */
    public function CategoriasAtivasAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $categorias = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Categoria')->findByAtivo(1);

        return $categorias;
    }
}
```

And i try access the service on ComandaController

```
class ComandaController extends Controller
{
...
public function newAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $comanda = new Comanda();

        $categorias = $this->get('categorias.ativas')->CategoriasAtivasAction();
...
```

Then symfony return error

`Call to a member function has() on null
500 Internal Server Error - FatalThrowableError`

My services.yml has

```
services:
  categorias.ativas:
     class: AppBundle\Controller\AccessClassController
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: You can't use a Controller (extending Controller) as a service.

Comment: Actually you can as long as you inject the container.  Doesn't make much sense to do so.  And in this case, it is the ComandaController which is bbeing created somewhere without the container.  Hence the has error.

Answer (score 2):

As per Symfony documentation, Defining controllers as services is not officially recommended by Symfony. Even though if you need to use you can do that. As per your code you haven't passed service container object in service. Please do the following changes and try.

In your services.yml file

```
services:
   categorias.ativas:
      class: AppBundle\Controller\AccessClassController
      arguments: ["@service_container"]
```

And in your AccessClassController file

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class AccessClassController extends Controller{

  /**
  * Retorna todas as categorias ativas
  */
  public function CategoriasAtivasAction()
  {
    $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();

    $categorias = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Categoria')->findByAtivo(1);

    return $categorias;
  }
}
```